# Collection partial lazy download

Tags: javascript, algorithm, collections, download, client

I am looking for an elegant way to lazy download and cache items from a collection on the client.

Let's say you request batch from 0-50 than from 174-223 etc...
Is somebody familiar with a library or algorithm that handles such problem?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Perhaps describe a situation in which you would use this.

Comment: @pablochan sure but what exactly leaves you wondering?

Comment: The problem is that I (and perhaps others) don't understand your problem. This makes it difficult to answer the question.

Comment: @pablochan For instance imagine a pagination view where somebody jumps on different batches of items and the client must download and cache the batches on request.
So I am looking for a way to handle this process of getting items from memory or lazy download them

Comment: @pablochan Then the batch stored in js array or map  is used for showing on the view for the user to see

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine a simple function for fetching data.

```
function fetch(from: Number, to: Number): Promise<Object>
```

This function takes a range and returns a `Promise` that will resolve to the data we want (what that data is, is not important). Let's say that the function calls a server every time to get the data. If you know that the data on the server won't change, we can add caching in a very simple way. We just need to create a function that will use `fetch` internally and just save the results. The most basic approach could look like this.

```
function makeCachedFetch() {
  var cache = {};
  return function cachedFetch(from, to) {
     var key = from + '-' + to;
     if (!cache[key]) {
       // we keep promises in the cache
       cache[key] = fetch(from, to);
     }
     return cache[key];
  };
}

// now we just make an instance of our cached fetch function
var cachedFetch = makeCachedFetch();
// this will call the server
cachedFetch(0, 50);
// bu this won't
cachedFetch(0, 50);
```

Obviously this doesn't work if you don't ask for exactly the same ranges over and over, even if the data itself is cached, but it should be a good starting point for you.

Comment: Thank you for your effort +1 but that I figured out myself I need more sophisticated solution. However that is my fault I wasn't clear enough.
I do appreciate your kind help.

Comment: I figured out as much, that's why I asked you to be specific. If you have a solution, please post it as an answer here. It may be useful for others.